# Why rails platform developers are changing the syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am new to Rails. I am learning rails 2.3.5 and checked Rails 3.
I found some features added in Rails 3. That's perfectly fine. But I found something different. 
in 2.3.5 we use

```
  ruby script/server
```

to start the server and in Rails 3 we use

```
  rails server
```

and there are some other changes like this. What's the improvement by doing this?

What's the basic difference between this? Can anybody give me a list of these changes and explanations for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cleaner. To use a single executable for the Rails framework is much more DRY than using tons of scripts in the `script` folder that are always the exact same thing.

Also, it's fewer keystrokes. Who can complain about that? :)

As far as a list goes, anything you once used `script` for is now under the `rails` binary. You can run `rails help` in a Rails 3 project to see a list of possible arguments.

Comment: Does `ruby script/server` still work? If so then this is a good thing. If not then breaking changes for the lose.

Comment: @Earlz:  `ruby script/server` no longer works.  It's not "for the lose".  This is a new platform, not an extension of Rails 1.x, and as such, they are creating new conventions.

Comment: @Earlz - Rails 3 is a brand new system with brand new syntax. It is well-known that it is not compatible with Rails 2, and, though certain things have just been deprecated instead of removed entirely, backwards-compatibility is not the goal here - especially since, generally, only a human being ever calls `script/server`, or anything else in `script/`, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, if you're new to Rails, by all means stick to 2.3 for a while. Rails 3.0 is still in beta, and the documentation and articles you'll find mostly cover 2.3.

That said, the [release notes](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html) cover all the changes briefly, and links to articles explaining the gory details. Don't be surprised if some it overwhelms you though, you'll need a good understanding of all the Rails concepts to follow along.